# HiddenFor value is empty

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a view

```
   @using (@Html.BeginForm())
   {
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Person</h4>
        <hr/>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PersonId)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(Gender)))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Gender)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And ViewModel

```
public class Person
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}

public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female
}
```

The problem is validation complaints about PersonId being null.
It renders in browser as such (see, value is empty, but should be zero).

```
<div class="form-group">
     <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The PersonId field is required." id="PersonId" name="PersonId" value="" type="hidden">
</div>
```

Could you please help? I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.8 RC2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't initialize object (Person) so the value is empty.

[image]

You could do as below then the value will not be empty.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue indeed